# Highlight triplicates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to highlight triplicates values in my whole excel table

[image]

However it is not working with what I tried :

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$H$24,$B$3:$H$24)>=3
```

I know that this formula is incorrect, it says: count every `$B$3:$H$24` in the whole range: `$B$3:$H$24`.. this doesn't mean anything...

What I want is the exact same function as the native excel option : "Highlight duplicate" which can apply to a whole table.

I applied this formula to the "highlight" functionality of excel which itself applies to table range which is `$B$3:$H$24`

This would be an exemple of an expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on cell **B3** and create a New Rule in Conditional Formatting with the FormulaIs option:

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$H$24,B3)>=3
```

and then pick a hi-light color.  Then copy cell **B3** and PasteSpecialFormats onto all the cells in **B3** through **H24**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select the `$B$3:$H$24` area, then apply the following formula as a condition for its formatting:

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$H$24,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))>2
```

Pick the format you prefer